# Column doesn't center when it drops bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I've got this code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4"> </div>
```

When it breaks(1 column/row) the column isn't center. How can I center it?

Comment: Do you mean the content isn't centered or the column is not centered on the screen?

Comment: Inside the column it's a picture, so the picture isn't centered. It's wrapped in a container&a row.

Answer (score 0):

Use the class `center-block`.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-4">
    <img class="center-block" ... />
</div>
```

[Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-center)